# Eclipse always runs all projects - how can I only run one?

Tags: eclipse, project

OK, I'm an Eclipse noob, just working through the first couple of Plug-In creation tutorials and I have this really annoying problem: I can't figure out how to stop Eclipse from always building all projects when I only want to run one of them.

Let me elaborate: I have project A (Java), B (Java) and C (Python). They're completely unrelated, i.e. there are no dependencies whatsoever between them. Project A even lives in a seperate working set. Now I try to run project A, but I get error messages about problems in projects B and C - why is that? How can I only build the current project?

There's also another problem that's probably related: When I start my plug-in as an Eclipse application, all the other plug-ins I wrote before are also included in the Eclipse instance that is started. Is this a seperate phenomenon or does it follow from my first problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click the projects you do not want running and select 'Close Project'

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks a bunch! That fixed the problem. Just one additional piece of info: You could alternatively right click on the project you do want running and select "Close unrelated projects".

Answer (score 0):

i i work with eclipse 
if you want to start only one project you have to click on the arrow near the green circle
it's the icon right from this bug. then "opens a kind of list where your can choose"
then choose run "your class"

i work with eclipse classic and have 3 java swing projects. that's the way it works by me.